# chrome.browserAction.setPopup({}) doesn't show popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to display different popups depend on the status of the user (logged-in or not). In `background.js` and after do the test I set a popup to display like this:

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

        function buttonClicked(tab) {
            console.log("function working")
             // ...
                    chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "main.html"});
// ...

}
```

when I click the extension icon I got the messgage `function working` in the the log, but the popup doesn't display until I click the second time on the extension icon.

 I want to display it at the first click, how can I do this.

Comment: onClicked can't be used together with an html file. If you want the popup html, don't use onClicked.

Comment: @wOxxOm so what is the solution

Comment: Don't use chrome.browserAction.onClicked.

Comment: @wOxxOm there is an alternative?

Comment: Yes, just do it in your popup js script. Or in another listener in the background script.

Comment: so how do you do this??

Comment: @johnktejik  maybe I tried it and it did not work. There  a while since I post this question.